# Android: Display Notification as an activity instead of adding it to status bar

Tags: android, notifications

I m a newbie to android development and i wanna know a right way to get notification as an activity instead of statusbar notification.

To be clear, i wanna display an notification on screen instead of adding it to status bar.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you shouldn't call it notification. In Android, a notification is something that ends up in the status bar and that the user can deal with at her own leisure.

An activity will take over the complete screen and force the user to deal with it immediately. That is very intrusive and users will likely get annoyed, unless the information you show is really crucial.

The correct behaviour is to post a notification and bring up your activity when the user clicks on the notification, very much like your messaging client or email client.

Other options are bringing up a dialogue or a toaster message. A dialogue is a message the user will have to interact with to go away, whereas a toaster message will be visible for a short time and then automatically disappear.

Maybe you could be a bit more specific about what sort of information you want to provide to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can be helped out.
I feel that you are getting notifications from a web service as a response to some request, right?
If yes, then you can display them in a custom made dialog box, or inside an activity whose theme has been set as DIALOG.

maybe I got your question wrong, maybe your talking about the notifications about networks, calls and things.
If its so, correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually,i needed notifications for email application. For example, on any new mail received,etc., On any such event occur an activity containing that application icon, from where notification has occured and information about the event should be displayed along with two buttons. On click of positive button certain action should be performed, for example in case of new mail arrival, that mail should be opened.

Comment: I have created an application for this kind of notification.

Comment: Okay I got it (Almost, perhaps). You will have to make your activity listen to Broadcast Messages that are relayed when certain global events occur, like: email received, call received, sms received. check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#broadlife

Comment: So whenever an email is received, your activity gets notified and then you can do whatever you want to after knowing that an email has arrived. but i am not sure whether this will bar the notification from going into notification bar

Comment: I needed an right way to achieve the above feature. My requirement is, my notification activity should be accessible from all the applications.

Comment: From all the applications?? means whenever any email arrives, you should get notified??

Comment: From all the applications means, we just want to replace the current notification service with this our own notification.

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.3 introduced a new field on Notification, [`fullScreenIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean%29), for exactly this purpose. Place a `PendingIntent` here that will trigger whatever activity you'd like to display, and the user will be sent to that activity (whether full-screen or dialog-themed) in addition to receiving the usual notification icon in the status bar. As of Gingerbread, this is how the Phone app implements the incoming call screen.